# Can I apply after standard UK visa refusal to a different type of UK visa?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, russia

I've received a refusal in Standard Visitor visa at February this year. I'm a pensioner, 64, I live in Moscow, previously visited UK 11 times, in a period from 2006 to 2019, I had 7 UK visas.

Can I apply again, but for a different type of visa, for example, for a marriage visa?

As I understand now, the situation with tourists visas has become more complicated after the pandemic - for example, in the past times itemized banking transactions was not required, it was sufficient to provide the bank certificate of my account. In December 2022, I applied for a regular tourist visa, fulfilled exactly the same requirements for my application, as I did in previous years, but was refused under paragraphs 4.2 and (c) of the Appendix V. I never ever could imagine, that my immaculate visa history would mean nothing, and I'd be suspected in deceit.

Comment: Do you actually qualify for another visa class at all?

Comment: Uploading a copy of the refusal letter with personal details redacted would help you get an answer. However in principal there is nothing to stop you from applying for a different visa class after a visitor visa refusal, *providing you qualify for the visa class you want to apply for.*

Comment: A refusal under V4.2 means UKVI were not convinced you are a genuine visitor who will leave at the end of your trip. Given your previous UK visa history, that decision probably has a lot to do with current immigration risk appetite related to your citizenship/place of residence. It’s likely therefore that you would not be given a Marriage Visitor visa either. To get an *immigrant* marriage visa, proving that it is not a *sham marriage* or a *marriage of convenience* to gain an immigration advantage would be critical.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the situation, Traveller. I think that proving must be also related to the person I want to marriage.  I have my refusal at PDF/Adobe, and I tried to upload it, but my attempts weren't successful.

Comment: I don't think I qualify, Nicolas Formichella. I think Kafka would cry a river, if he'd get a chance to read Immigration and Visa Rules. And Mr. Orwell would probably say, well, it wasn't too hard to predict.

Comment: If you don't qualify for another route than SVV, then don't apply to anything else than SVV. Applying for things you don't qualify for can be easily seen as being desperate above not being able to read the rules

Comment: Thank you,NIcolas Formichella! I have my love in England, we deeply love each other, and we are acquainted for a few years, everyday we are on connection.  Its kind of surreal situation for us, how to unite, having such hindrances as visa permission.  Which, actually, never was a hundrance before pandemic and war.

Answer (score 1):

Combining comments into an answer:

A refusal under V4.2 means UKVI were not convinced you are a genuine visitor who will leave at the end of your trip. Given your previous UK visa history, that decision probably has a lot to do with current immigration risk appetite related to your citizenship/place of residence. It’s likely therefore that you would not be given a Marriage Visitor visa either. To get an *immigrant* marriage visa, proving that it is not a sham marriage or a marriage of convenience to gain an immigration advantage would be critical.

As @Nicolas Formichella commented: If you don't qualify for another route than SVV, then don't apply to anything else than SVV. Applying for things you don't qualify for can be easily seen as being desperate, over and above not being able to read the rules.

See also this canonical Q&A [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) which covers the specific reasons you say were given in your refusal, and mentions the existence of a list of countries where historical performance has been problematic. Applicants in these countries will have a more difficult time. The list is classified, but I’d put money on Russia having being added to that list as a result of its invasion of Ukraine.